# Create multiple times works, but not in for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, break

Have what I think seems like a kind of strange problem.
I have a function that is made to draw an element in HTML5.
If i write it multiple times it is drawn those times, but if i place it in a loop it only draws the first time. Iv tried to monitor this by console.log for example but as soon as i try to draw this the loop is interrupted. It like there is some type of "break" function in it.

Anyone who has an idea about this?

```
<body>
   <section id="wrapper">
        <h1></h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style=" border-color: #000; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>

        <script>
            var context;
            var canvas;
            var WIDTH;
            var HEIGHT;


            $(document).ready(function() {

                main_init();

            });
            function main_init() {
                console.log("init");
                WIDTH = $("#canvas").width();
                HEIGHT = $("#canvas").height();
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');



                var width = 10;
                var height = 10;

                var posX = 30;
                var posY = 60;

                //NOT WORKING
                for(y = 1; y < height; y+=1)
                {           
                    for(x = 1; x < width; x+=1)
                    {
                        console.log("y:"+ y + " x:" + x);
                        //console.log(isEven(x));
                            if(isEven(x))
                            {               
                              HexagonObj(posX * x, posY * y, 0.95);
                            }
                            else
                            {                   
                              HexagonObj(posX * x, (posY + 20) * y, 0.95);
                            }
                    }
                }

                //WORKING
                HexagonObj(-30, 60, 0.95);
                HexagonObj(10, 80, 0.95);
                HexagonObj(50, 60, 0.95);

                HexagonObj(-30, 100, 0.95);

            }


            HexagonObj = function(xCorrd, yCorrd, size){
                //console.log("hexagon");

                var x0=xCorrd; var y0=yCorrd; //cordinates
                var xx=20 * size; var yy=20 * size; //size of the legs of the shape

                x=x0; y=y0; context.moveTo(x,y);
                x+=xx; y+=0;  context.moveTo(x,y);
                x+=xx; y+=0;  context.lineTo(x,y);
                x+=xx; y+=yy; context.lineTo(x,y);
                x+=(xx*-1); y+=yy; context.lineTo(x,y);
                x+=(xx*-1); y+=0; context.lineTo(x,y);
                x+=(xx*-1); y+=(yy*-1); context.lineTo(x,y);
                x+=xx; y+=(yy*-1); context.lineTo(x,y);

                context.fillStyle = "#FFFF99";
                context.fill();

                context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";    
                context.stroke();

            }

            function isEven(n) 
            {
               return parseFloat(n) && (n % 2 == 0);
            }


        </script>
    </section>
</body>
```

I have marked the `HexagonObj` creation that works and that dose not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `x` and `y` as variables in each function where they are used. Because you are missing the `var` declaration, the functions are all accessing global `x` and `y` variables. As a consequence, the first call to `HexagonObj` clobbers the loop variables in `main_init()`.

(Technically, you only need to declare `var x, y` in one of the functions to solve the immediate problem. However, it's bad form to be using global variables like that.)

Comment: Feel kind of sloppy for missing that. Thanks for the help finding the problem. :]

Answer (score 0):

for loop executing only once in function `main_init` since `x` and `y` which are global are modified inside `HexagonObj` function to `y:81 and x:50`